# mongosh - $concat for one field in updateOne method

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongo-shell, mongodb-update

I want to update a particular document for the email field based on its id, but I don't want to overwrite the email field completely. Instead, I just want to add a string beside it (concatenate it with another string), I.e. I need the current value of the email and add a string beside it.

For example, if the email field in the document was `example@email.com`, I want to update it to become `example@email.com___deleted`.

Here's what I've tried, but it's showing me an error

```
db.testme.updateOne({_id: ObjectId("626bc5ddd6e2abe315ff8c76")}, {$set: {$concat: {email: ['$email', '___deleted']}} })
```

> MongoServerError: The dollar ($) prefixed field '$concat' in '$concat'
> is not allowed in the context of an update's replacement document.
> Consider using an aggregation pipeline with $replaceWith.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Update with Aggregation Pipeline](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/).

```
db.testme.updateOne({
  _id: ObjectId("626bc5ddd6e2abe315ff8c76")
},
[
  {
    $set: {
      email: {
        $concat: [
          "$email",
          "___deleted"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/NhaD9QTZYbC)

Comment: That's it! thanks for answering, when I read the error, I thought it wants me to use the method aggregate, like `db.testme.aggregate()`